Finder search shows 0 results for searches inside user folder
It seems from a bit of research that Finder search is a frequent source of issues for people, and I have tried the standard System Settings and mdutil approaches to rebuild the Spotlight database, but they don't seem to have had any effect. What's more confusing is that all the files are indeed indexed, since I can find files in the "This Mac" tab for a search which are located in my user folder which shows me 0 items when searched directly in the other tab. I have no folders set to private in the Spotlight settings, but it seems as though Finder is only permitted to search my user folder from the "perspective" of the whole drive.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What MacOS version? Please explain exactly what you're trying to do, and what happens when you do it. (Also: if you search for problems, you'll see that everything is a source of issues.)
